# Update the MS Access table using the ComboBox using a VBA to generate Auto Numbers

Tags: vba, ms-access, autonumber

The idea is when a Number is provided in the combobox, the update query runs to update the table with the provided number of records.

Ex: If 100 entered then 100 records should gets updated.

[image: Here is the VBA to create the AutoNumber]

And here is the Query. 
[image: that uses the Auto Number function to update the table from the Number entered from the ComboBox]

I have observed the query does not work with the Filters, getting the wrong number of records.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Should post code (VBA and query) in question as text, not images.

Comment: Sample of table structure & raw dats as well as desired result could also be useful (again, as text in question). Why the i argument if it is not used in function?

Comment: I tested this and seems to work.